# Looping a function over huge dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, finance

A (already defined) function takes ISIN (unique identifier in finance) as input and gets the corresponding RIC (another identifier) as output by looking at a particular internal web app where this data is available in tabular form. The Key limitation of this website is that it can't take more than 500 input ID at a time. So when 500 or less number of ISINs are entered as input it returns a dataframe containing 500 input ISIN and their corresponding RIC codes from the website.

Task is to take a csv as input containing 30k ISINs and batch them in group of 500 IDs so that it can pass through the function and then store the produced output (dataframe). Keep looping input and appending output incrementally.

Can someone please suggest how to break this data of 30K into size of 500 and then loop through function and store all results? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

.iloc is the method you want to use.

```
df.iloc[firstrow:lastrow , firstcol:lastcol]
```

if you put it in a for loop such as

```
for x in range (0, 30000, 50):
  a = x #first row
  b = x+50 #last row
  thisDF = bigdf.iloc[a:b , firstcol:lastcol]
```

Try it and implement it in your code. You should make questions with some code you tried, so you get helped better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read in the .csv file as a pandas Series (e.g., by using something like this: `pd.Series.from_csv('ISINs.csv')`) or that you have a list, you could split these up as thus:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# mock series of ISINs
isins = pd.Series(np.arange(0, 30002, 1))

data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, len(isins)//500):
    isins_for_function = isins.iloc[i*500: i*500+500]
    # if you have a list instead of a series, you will need to split it like this instead
    isins_for_function = isins[i*500: i*500+500]

    df = func(isins_for_function)
    
    data = pd.concat([data, df])
# for Series
df = func(isins.iloc[-(len(isins)%500):]
# for list
df = func(isins[-(len(isins)%500):]
data = pd.concat([data, df])
```

This will concatenate your dataframes together into `data`.  `isins` is your Series/list of isins.  You will need the last bit after the for loop for any index values that are after the last chunk of 500 (in the Series above, which has 30002 rows, the last two are not included in the chunks of 500 so still need to be entered into the function `func`).